# How to remove padding from angular material dialog boxes?

Tags: angular-material2

Please see below link for issue description.

I want to remove the blue circled spaces. Thhis padding is showing by default. (how to set padding top, bottom, left and right to 0px)

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/14388

Thanks for you help

.html code

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

.ts code

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
}

/**
 * @title Dialog Overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['dialog-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: In your case these are called paddings and not margins - please see answer below. If anything is unclear respond in the comments and I'll explain it further ;)

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: Just tried this in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-dialogs-sample?file=styles.scss) and it works perfectly - please look at my edit & try yourself

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who may still need this (working with Angular Material **7 and above**).

The right solution is adding a class when opening the dialog:

```js
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
// ...
this._dialog.open(SomeComponent, { panelClass: "foo" });
```

and then in my `some-component.component.scss`

```css
/* SCSS */
.foo .mat-dialog-container  {
  padding: 0;
}
```

[blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-dialogs-sample-v4fesu)

Comment: this is right solution but styles must be global not in component

Comment: @danday74 not true. Did you open the blitz? `ViewEncapsulation.None` solves the problem. A bit ugly, but there's really no other solution, since the `.mat-dialog-container` is created outside the component.

Comment: ah ok thx I didn't know about ViewEncapsulation - good to know thx - although I'm guessing it makes the components styles global